# ROS2 Functionality Documentation

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there, I am totally new to using ROS and ROS2. Excuse me for my newbie behavior but is there any documentation on how I can use the API for ROS or ROS2? There are many classes and functions, so I got lost while attempting to write code on my own. If you could provide some help or documentation, I'd appreciate it quite a lot. I have gone through most of the tutorials, so I have not found what I needed there. Namely, I want to work with 32 bit integer arrays from the package "example_interfaces" package. I have not been able to find documentation for it nor did I get help from IntelliSense for the functions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392070/ros2-functionality-documentation/) by [fyzegekmc](https://answers.ros.org/users/86880/fyzegekmc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could start learning by [reviewing a sample code](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclpy/topics/pointcloud_publisher/examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher/pointcloud_publisher.py) for the ROS2 Python Pointcloud Publisher. With exception of `sensor_msgs_py` and use of `numpy`, it is a basic example of working with a message type with an array inside. You should add your initial basic code in your question so we can help you better with your problems.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fyzegekmc](https://answers.ros.org/users/86880/fyzegekmc/) on 2021-12-03**:
Dear ljaniec,

Thanks for the time taken to respond and giving me a good example. The example you have provided me is a good place to begin, however, instead of needing to transmit point cloud data, I am actually planning to transmit data pertaining to a stream of images, rather than pure 32 bit integers. Excuse me for me the relatively short description of my problem. I'll be looking towards other solutions including either some pre-written package which I can also include in my environment/workspace or opting to use a rather simpler architecture that may not involve ROS at all.

Best regards,
Feyzi

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can learn 2 api of ROS 2, [rclcpp](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/index.html) and [rclpy](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclpy/index.html). it is not exhaustive but is very commonly used. It can also help you better understand the documentation on ros2

---

Originally posted by [Staredeath](https://answers.ros.org/users/89081/staredeath/) with karma: 21 on 2021-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fyzegekmc](https://answers.ros.org/users/86880/fyzegekmc/) on 2021-12-03**:
Dear Staredeath,
I'll be looking towards the API Documentation as per the links provided by you. Thanks for the tip.
Best regards,
Feyzi